# VL53L0X constantly returns range_error

Tags: range-detector

I'm trying to get a [VL53L0X](https://www.st.com/en/imaging-and-photonics-solutions/vl53l0x.html) range sensor to work, but anything other than the basic init functions returns a range_error. I'm using the API provided by ST compiled into a DLL.

I can communicate with the sensor using I2C i.e. reading regs `0xC0` and `0xC1` does return the expected `0xEE` and `0xAA`. Running `dataInit()` and `staticInit()` works without issues.

However once I get to calibration or actual range measurements, the sensor throws a `VL53L0X_ERROR_RANGE_ERROR` or `-6` during the calibrations, i.e. `VL53L0X_PerformRefSpadManagement()` and `VL53L0X_PerformRefCalibration()`. This is caused by the `VL53L0X_GetInterruptMaskStatus()` function where apparently two bits are set which the API doesn't like. So I ignored these calibrations for now, since a) they appear to be optional, and b) an [apparent ST employee wrote on their forum](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00000wxvrWSAQ/vl53l0x-api-initialization-error-performrefspadmanagement-returns-6-vl53l0xerrorrangeerror):

> I've seen that happen. But it only happens on some some sensors and it occurs when the pre->calibrated data matches your result. So, in effect, you can skip that error knowing that >the pre-calibrated data is fine.

Now when I start a single measurement `VL53L0X_PerformSingleRangingMeasurement()` this also returns a `VL53L0X_ERROR_RANGE_ERROR`. This time because the wait-for_data loop times out.

So I'm guessing I'm still missing something here? Did anyone have the same issues and fixed it?

Update: The two calibration functions still return `-6` but I'm not overly concerned with these right now. I figured out, that the default config of the sensor isn't working. I found some configs from ST for different applications [here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um2039-world-smallest-timeofflight-ranging-and-gesture-detection-sensor-application-programming-interface-stmicroelectronics.pdf) (or from the examples in their API). So my config (before calling a ranging measurement) looks like this:

```
VL53L0X_Error VL53L0X_SetConfig()
{
    VL53L0X_Error Status = VL53L0X_ERROR_NONE;

    if (Status == VL53L0X_ERROR_NONE) {
        Status = VL53L0X_SetLimitCheckEnable(&myDev,
            VL53L0X_CHECKENABLE_SIGMA_FINAL_RANGE, 1);
    }
    if (Status == VL53L0X_ERROR_NONE) {
        Status = VL53L0X_SetLimitCheckEnable(&myDev,
            VL53L0X_CHECKENABLE_SIGNAL_RATE_FINAL_RANGE, 1);
    }

    if (Status == VL53L0X_ERROR_NONE) {
        Status = VL53L0X_SetLimitCheckValue(&myDev,
            VL53L0X_CHECKENABLE_SIGNAL_RATE_FINAL_RANGE,
            (FixPoint1616_t)(0.25 * 65536));
    }
    if (Status == VL53L0X_ERROR_NONE) {
        Status = VL53L0X_SetLimitCheckValue(&myDev,
            VL53L0X_CHECKENABLE_SIGMA_FINAL_RANGE,
            (FixPoint1616_t)(18 * 65536));
    }
    if (Status == VL53L0X_ERROR_NONE) {
        Status = VL53L0X_SetMeasurementTimingBudgetMicroSeconds(&myDev,
            33000);
    }

    if (Status == VL53L0X_ERROR_NONE) {
        Status = VL53L0X_SetVcselPulsePeriod(&myDev,
            VL53L0X_VCSEL_PERIOD_PRE_RANGE, 18);
    }
    if (Status == VL53L0X_ERROR_NONE) {
        Status = VL53L0X_SetVcselPulsePeriod(&myDev,
            VL53L0X_VCSEL_PERIOD_FINAL_RANGE, 14);
    }


    return Status;
}
```

The overall flow is something like:

```
    int vl_error = 0;

    if (vl_error == 0)
    {
        vl_error |= VL53L0X.VL53L0X_DataInit_devless();
    }
    if (vl_error == 0)
    {
        vl_error |= VL53L0X.VL53L0X_StaticInit_devless();
    }
    
    if (vl_error == 0)
    {
        vl_error |= VL53L0X.VL53L0X_PerformRefSpadManagement_devless(mRefSpadCnt, isApertureSpads);
        vl_error = 0;
    }
    

    if (vl_error == 0)
    {
        vl_error |=  VL53L0X.VL53L0X_PerformRefCalibration_devless();
        vl_error = 0;
    }

    if (vl_error == 0)
    {
        vl_error |= VL53L0X.VL53L0X_SetDeviceMode_devless(0);
    }

    if (vl_error == 0)
    {
        vl_error |= VL53L0X.VL53L0X_SetConfig_devless();
    }

    if (vl_error == 0)
    {
        vl_error |= VL53L0X.VL53L0X_PerformSingleRangingMeasurement_devless();
    }

    return true;
}
```

`PerformSingleRangingMeasurement()` exits with no error but does not give a range measurement. Instead the range in mm is constantly 8191 and the range status is 2 which indicates a signal fail:

> This value indicate that the signal check has failed. This can happens when there is no target or when the Range Ignore threshold check has failed. Use the function VL53L0X_SetLimitCheckEnable() and VL53L0X_SetLimitCheckValue() to manage the limit.

I tried different values for `SetLimitCheckValue` but allways get the same result. If I try and other configs (suggested by ST), i.e. high accuracy, high speed or the default, the measurement will timeout again.

Comment: I'm guessing you used the software provided https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/ecosystems/stm32-open-development-environment/stm32cube-expansion-software/stm32-ode-sense-sw/x-cube-53l0a1.html

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 No, I got the API from here: https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/embedded-software/imaging-software/stsw-img005.html

Comment: Do you have anything over the sensor, plastic, glass, etc.. ?

Comment: No, just the sensor pointing at a white wall at about 50cm away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I didn't find a satisfying answer, but one that works (at least somewhat).

As described in [this](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000C6d8GfSQI/vl53l0x-returns-0x1ffff-8191) thread, removing the `VL53L0X_set_reference_spads()` call from the API during the `staticInit()' at least lets me read measurements.

An ST employee suggested (in the same thread)

> The trick, when this happens, is to set the RefSpad to 3 and try again. By bringing the RefSpad back to 'nominal', the calibration will pass.

however, this didn't work for me but might be helpful for someone else in the future.

As I said, after I removed that one line from the API, everything worked. There is an offset on the range measurements but this can be fixed with some calibrations. No idea what problems with this I will run into further down the line, but at least the sensor is now responsive and I can continue development.

Bottom line is: Everyone working with a VL53L0X said not to bother with it but get a VL53L1X instead...